# UITableView not reusing cells with storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I'm developing an iOS 7+ app, and I've some `UITableViewController` in storyboard that are showing a weird behavior. I've a basic prototype cell defined in one of them, with an identifier @"standardCell" also set in storyboard. In the associated `UITableViewController` class, I've this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   // Return the number of sections.
   return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   // Return the number of rows in the section.
   return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"standardCell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   }

   cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];

   return cell;
}
```

Cells are loaded the first tiem the table view is shown, but as soon as I scroll the table content, all cell titles that were set appear empty and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not called anymore. The `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method is neither called.

I've set both `delegate` and `dataSource` for this table view to be the table view controller. And its `.h` file conforms to `UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>`.

I find a similar issue with another table view and associated view controller, where prototype cell is a custom cell instead: cells show wrong data and weird content when I scroll the table, as if cells where not being dequeued and reused as expected.

What could I being missing?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Size classes?

Comment: @SarimSidd No, I'm not using neither size classes nor auto layout

Comment: what is UITableViewCellStyle in attributes inspector?

Comment: @SumitGarg prototype cell is set to `Basic` style

Comment: Why are you defining a prototype cell and then using the default UITableViewCell class in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @MikeTaverne I also have a similar problem with custom cells...

Answer (score 1):

at least in this method:

Change this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"standardCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

To this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"standardCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```